# React Web app after redirecting showing empty content after refreshing the page showing content

Tags: reactjs

In React Web Application After login it should redirect to a new page called Dashboard but initially its showing empty content once i refresh the page then only the contents are appearing on page

```
<div>
                <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={dashboard} />
```

Comment: I'm going to need a little more information about how your  `dashboard` component renders in order to help. Could we see what that component looks like? Could you also show us your full `router` file?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4vab3px7/ here is my full router